# Python3 - wifi library does not run with Cell.all("wlan0")

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi

I'm trying to use wifi library for python3 (https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but when I use Cell.all("wlan0") I get this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti sono riservati.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from wifi import Cell, scheme
>>> list(Cell.all("wlan0"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\-----\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\wifi\scan.py", line 39, in all
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "c:\users\-----\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\-----o\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 696, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\users\-----\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\-----\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato
>>>
```

p.s. Sorry for my bad English (I'm italian)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because you are running Windows. The wifi library is only designed for Linux systems as described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the question and thanks for the answer, I hit this same issue with my code. Let me try Linux and i will give you my feedback!